# Is there a maximum number of pods which can be bound to a pvc backed by AzureFiles?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I spun up a 1000 pods on my cluster and ~800 of them got stuck in ContainerCreating with the status:

`Warning  FailedMount  8s    kubelet, k8s-alsjkdf  Unable to mount volumes for pod "test-xvbbf_default(05706f3d-12a2-11e8-9e41-000d3a028eee)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"test-xvbbf". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[some list of volumes] 
Warning  FailedSync   8s    kubelet, k8s-alsjkdf  Error syncing pod`

I noticed that ~60 of my pods were running at one time. All these pods share the same PVCs.

I couldn't find any mention of a limit in the Kubernetes documentation. The documentation for AzureFiles, which back the PVs, state that they support like 2000 (or something like that) concurrent handlers so I don't think that's an issue.

Is this a known limit in Kubernetes, or is it in some configuration?

Note: The pods all eventually completed, I'm not worried about that.

Comment: Just for testing, can you canche the type of filesystem used for your volumes? (as in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32187)

Comment: I'm sorry, what does 'canche' mean in this context?

Comment: I am sorry too, It was a bit late yesterday when I typed that comment. I suspect I meant "change", as in "from today's testing, I changed fsType: ntfs-3g, it works well." of the issue I mention above.

Comment: I'd have to look into it. Either way, I'm not sure how that is pertinent to the question. I appreciate the problem solving, don't get me wrong, but this question was more to sate my curiosity. Unless are you suggesting that this limitation might be present in other FS, and that I should experiment to determine whether that is the case?

Comment: Yes, I thought the file system might be the limiting factor here.

Comment: Are you use AKS?

Comment: No.  AKS doesn't support private VNets yet. Until it does that isn't a feasible option.

Comment: @VonC I'm pretty sure that I didn't have this problem when I was using Gluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into a limitation on the number of disks that can be attached to a node at any given time.

For a Basic Tier VM, the maximum number of highly utilized disks is about 66 (20,000/300 IOPS per disk), and for a Standard Tier VM, it is about 40 (20,000/500 IOPS per disk).